# design pattern for exception handling in database layer

Tags: java, spring-data

My system has 2 main layers, the service layer and the database access layer.

I expose an interface to the service layer for the database operations.

Now, in this interface there are a few exceptions that can get thrown by every operation of the DAO layer for example, timeout exceptions etc-

Is there a way to express this specification other than explicitly specifying for every method with `throws ExceptionName`?

Comment: Cool. But I'd think I will try the checked heirarchical exceptions then.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple of options here; but I *think* my "opinion" somehow matches up with the "best practices" that you will find in many places by now:

- If you want to use checked exceptions, then create some abstract base exception and put that one on your throws list. Because you **really** do not want more than one, two exceptions on your throws list. Simply because such extensive throw lists grow over time, and they quickly **pollute** all your layers.
- You can also go for not using checked exceptions! Instead: throw appropriate runtime exceptions, and document that fact via javadoc on your interfaces. Many people argue that the "war" between checked and unchecked exceptions is **over**, and that **unchecked** won. Because you need some "generic everything catching" thing on top anyway. So, when that code will be written anyway, why the hustle and bustle with those maintenance-intensive throw lists?!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to express this specification other than explicitly specifying for every method with throws ExceptionName?

There isn't.  Sorry.

You could potentially reduce the amount of boilerplate by (re-)implementing your custom exceptions as a hierarchy.  But unless you want your exceptions to be unchecked<sup>1</sup>, then some boilerplate is necessary.

---

<sup>1 - That has downsides too.  You lose compile time checks for exceptions that are not handled if you make then unchecked.</sup>